# How to detect memory stress, memory reclaim aggressiveness, or OOM kill level in android?

Tags: android

I'm writing a application with a ~1GB memory footprint.
The app works fine on devices with 4GB memory but on devices with less than 3GB of memory it will trigger aggressive memory reclaim and sometimes trigger OOM killer and degrade user experience on a system level, (e.g. it takes a long time to go back to the previous app, music player in the background gets killed.)

I'm wondering if it's possible to query system memory status and adjust the memory usage of my app accordingly, e.g. use memory conservatively before the system is about to kill processes of `ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_SERVICE` level.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you may want to profile your app to see you really need that much memory constantly allocated:

- [Manage Your App's Memory](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory.html)
- [Investigating Your RAM Usage](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/investigate-ram.html)

Then you have [onTrimMemory()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentCallbacks2.html#onTrimMemory(int)) callback (API 14+), you can use to free some resources when devices is short of them:

> Called when the operating system has determined that it is a good time
>   for a process to trim unneeded memory from its process. This will
>   happen for example when it goes in the background and there is not
>   enough memory to keep as many background processes running as desired.